# Cannot locate redis-server

Tags: python, bash, redis, config, redis-server

- I am working on Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL).
- I am trying to run a python file which has dependencies on redis package. When I run the python file it throws the error as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sachinbm/RELEXI/env_relexi/lib/python3.10/site-packages/smartsim/config.py", line 146, in redis_exe
    exe = expand_exe_path(redis_cli)
  File "/home/sachinbm/RELEXI/env_relexi/lib/python3.10/site-packages/smartsim/config.py", line 52, in expand_exe_path
    raise SSConfigError(f"Could not locate executable {exe}")
smartsim.error.errors.SSConfigError: Could not locate executable /home/sachinbm/RELEXI/env_relexi/lib/python3.10/site-packages/smartsim/bin/redis-server
```

whereas redis-server binary is present at

```
/usr/bin/redis-server
```

All the files redis-server, redis-cli, redis-benchmark, redis-check-aof, redis-check-rdb are present at

```
/usr/bin
```

The code that tries to access the redis-server binary is:

```
def redis_exe(self):
    try:
        redis_bin = self.conf["redis"]["bin"]
        redis_cli = osp.join(redis_bin, "redis-server")
        exe = expand_exe_path(redis_cli)
        return exe
    except KeyError:
        raise SSConfigError("Could not find redis.bin in SmartSim config")
    except SSConfigError as e:
        raise SSConfigError(
            "redis-server exe in SmartSim Config could not be used"
        ) from e
```

Please let me know how to get rid of this error. Should I edit bashrc or config file?

Comment: It seems smartsim is looking into the wrong folder as it expects the executable in `/home/sachinbm/RELEXI/env_relexi/lib/python3.10/site-packages/smartsim/bin/redis-server`. So, you need it to point to `/usr/bin/redis-server`. Can you show the code that tries to access the redis-server binary?

Comment: I have updated my original question with the code that tries to access the redis-server binary. Let me know if this is what you were expecting. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your problem. When I do `pip install smartsim` there is no file called `smartsim/config.py`. I'm also not sure what script you are calling. Which version of smartsim are you using? `pip freeze | grep smartsim`

Comment: I am using smartsim version 0.3.2
Basically I am trying to work on this package: https://github.com/flexi-framework/relexi
When I try to run ''' relexi.py ''' file it gives the above error

Comment: When I do `pip install smartsim==0.3.2`, the folder `python3.10/site-packages/smartsim/bin/` contains the `redis-server` application. Can you show the output of `ls -la /home/sachinbm/RELEXI/env_relexi/lib/python3.10/site-packages/smartsim/`? I think, there is an issue with your smartsim installation. It seems that `pip install smartsim` is not correctly resolving the redis dependency.

Comment: Please find the output of the command in the following link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MDSt_7edn2K0czbEsiViSMpcpRsGAD0C/view?usp=drive_link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the installation process of Relexi you are asked to execute the command
`smart --clobber`. This command removes the redis-server binary from the folder where `smartsim` expects it. Later the redis-server binary is installed in a different location. The problem is the changed folder structure between `smartsim==0.3.2` and later versions. It seems the ENV variables are not correctly assigned.

So, do:

```
pip install smartsim==0.3.2
smart --clobber # maybe avoid this line
smart --clean
smart --no_tf --no_pt -v
SMARTSIM_DIR=$(smart --site)
export PATH=$PATH:$SMARTSIM_DIR/bin # note that '_core/' was removed
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:${SMARTSIM_DIR}/lib # note that '_core/' was removed
```

And continue with the installation.

However, the question is strongly related to Relexi, and you should open an issue on the GitHub page. It is hard to track down the problem without knowing that you are trying to install Relexi.

Comment: Thank you very much. On uninstalling and reinstalling, the above method is giving the following output and it is the same as the output when I first installed with '--clobber' & '_core/'
PFA screenshot of the output:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/13Kijl9LMNdX3zbCGQSbnNCPqJMSl9GMs/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: You need to install git-lfs first:
`wget https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/releases/download/v3.4.0/git-lfs-linux-amd64-v3.4.0.tar.gz && tar -xzf git-lfs-linux-amd64-v3.4.0.tar.gz && cd git-lfs-3.4.0/ && bash install.sh`

Comment: The error " Could not locate executable redis-server " is no longer coming when I execute relexi.py. Now says " Starting SmartSim " and throws the error:
    raise SSConfigError(
smartsim.error.errors.SSConfigError: RedisAI library path provided in SmartSim config could not be found

Comment: Sorry, I can not help you further. As mentioned, please open an issue on the corresponding GitHub page.

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much for your support. It means a lot.